# How to upload a Codeigniter server to localhost in Tomcat?

Tags: php, codeigniter

An attempt was made to upload a CodeIgniter server to localhost.

Below is the part that took the setting

application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/ci/';
```

application/config/database.php :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'mysql',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'port' => '8080',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax4BZ.png)

I'm not sure what went wrong during setup. Give me advice if you have the same mistakes as me, or someone who has solved these problems.

Comment: is you localhost working? http://localhost:8080

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: just enter the url which I provided on your browser

Comment: I tried, but I can not connect to the site.

Comment: I do not use tools like xampp

Comment: it means your apache is not started. Turn it on

Comment: I understood about them. So I installed xampp. Currently xampp> root configuration in httpd.conf file is currently set to the project root of another computer. So I'm going to add another root in the httpd.conf file to run my projects from now on. If I do not know when I'm studying, can I keep asking you questions? Can you give me your Cacao Talk ID?